# Setting the correct height in vertical mode in Swiper

Tags: swiper.js

It's been days that I'm working on setting the swiper in my application but I still no luck and found no working sample anywhere from here to the Github issues or elsewhere on the net.

I can not set a dynamic height for the swiper in vertical mode via none of the suggested solutions to this problem.

I have several images as slides that give a height of thousands of pixels but if I switch it to a text it is fine as the height of the text is like 10 px. Any div above a certain height will result in abnormal height.

I found that the suggested CSS does not work as it just limits the height of the window and is very unpleasant as the pictures are cut off.

The js solutions are the correct way to do it but I can not find a working solution and the ones that I have tried all result in half of the job solutions.

It seems the correct way uses the onSlideChangeStart to correct the next slide height like below but this does not work as the swiper of the vertical is not recognized in its own settings.

```
onSlideChangeStart: (swiper)->
$(swiper.slides).each ->
    $(this).css height: if $(this).index() != swiper.activeIndex then 0 else 'auto'
```

I tried to use the active class instead of the API as it is not working when calling even the swiperV.activeIndex in its own onSlideChangeStart like below but swiper-slide-active is not defined.

This is my settings for the 3 nested sliders.

```
    var swiperVV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-vv', {
        direction: 'vertical',
        updateOnWindowResize: true,
        grabCursor: true,
        loop: true,
        mousewheel: true,
        lazy: true,
        zoom: true,
        effect: 'slide',
        spaceBetween: 0,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
            clickable: true,
        }, 
    });
    var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
        initialSlide:0,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        autoHeight: true,
        updateOnWindowResize: true,
        grabCursor: true,
        loop: true,
        parallax: true,
        lazy: true,
        effect: 'slide',
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination-h',
            clickable: true,
        },
        scrollbar: {
            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            hide: true,
        },
    });
    var swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
        direction: 'vertical',
        autoplay: {
            delay: 5000,
        },
        autoHeight: true,
        updateOnWindowResize: true,
        grabCursor: true,
        loop: true,
        mousewheel: true,
        lazy: true,
        zoom: true,
        effect: 'slide',
        spaceBetween: 0,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
            clickable: true,
        },
        slideChange: resizeSwiper()
    });

    function resizeSwiper() {
        console.log($('.swiper-container-v .swiper-slide swiper-slide-active').height());
        $('.swiper-container-v, .swiper-container-v .swiper-slide').css({ height: $('.swiper-container-v .swiper-slide .swiper-slide-active').height() });

    }
```

i have gone through all the samples of suggested users like the ones listed below in github, stackoverflow and codepen.
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/48
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/153

Answer (score 4):

This is the workaround worked for me

```
 if (typeof Swiper != "undefined"){
  var popularSwiper = new Swiper(".popularSwiper", {
    direction: "vertical",
    autoHeight: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    on:{
      init:function(){
        setSlideHeight(this);
      },
      slideChangeTransitionEnd:function(){
        setSlideHeight(this);
      }
    }
  });

  function setSlideHeight(that){
    $('.swiper-slide').css({height:'auto'});
        var currentSlide = that.activeIndex;
        var newHeight = $(that.slides[currentSlide]).height();

        $('.swiper-wrapper,.swiper-slide').css({ height : newHeight })
        that.update();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, passing the value `autoHeight: true,` as parameter on JS and simple CSS:

```
.swiper-slide {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

fixed the auto height issue. The slider wrapper will adapt its height to the height of the currently active slide.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

1. calculate the total height of the swiper container including gap between slides.
2. then set the swiper container height to the previously calculated height

```js
let pdpThumb = new Swiper('#pdp-thumbCarousel', {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            direction: 'vertical',
            spaceBetween: 10,
            freeMode: true,
            loop: true,
            on: {
                init: (swiper) => {
                    let totalGap = swiper.passedParams.spaceBetween * (swiper.passedParams.slidesPerView - 1);
                    let containerHeight = swiper.passedParams.slidesPerView * swiper.slides[0].clientHeight + totalGap;
                    swiper.el.style.height = containerHeight + 'px';
                },
            },
        });
```